# Change Color Based on Color Value Defined in Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, colors, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I want to use conditional formatting to change the color of cell B1 to the color I have defined in cell A1 (using hex values or anything else that will work).

For example, if I have "#FF0000" in cell A1, then B1 will turn red.
If I have "#00FF00" in cell A1, then B1 will turn green.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can't use conditional formatting for this.  You will need vba.

Comment: Let me rephrase.  To do this with conditional formatting, one would need to create a rule for every value A1 could be with the correct color output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to type a hex color value into a cell and have the cell to the right change to be whatever color you typed in. That can be done with VBA. This sub is written to leave in the Sheet object although you could generalize it to work in the Workbook object if you want it to apply to all sheets.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Declarations
    Dim watchRange As Range
    Dim val As String
    Dim valR As Integer, valG As Integer, valB As Integer
    
    ' Check that the target is in the range we care about
    Set watchRange = Range("A1:F10")
    If Not Intersect(watchRange, Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' Check that the cell has the right format
        val = Target.Value
        If Len(val) = 7 And Left(val, 1) = "#" Then
            ' Convert #RRGGBB to decimal RGB
            valR = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(val, 2, 2))
            valG = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(val, 4, 2))
            valB = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Mid(val, 6, 2))
            
            ' Color the cell
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(valR, valG, valB)
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

The part you really need to change is this bit:
`Set watchRange = Range("A1:F10")`
That tells VBA that you only care about changing colors if the cell you changed is within that range. Without this bit, it'll trigger the event whenever you change any cell anywhere. Another key point is that will only fire when you type in a new color. Deleting the cell contents will not return the neighboring cell to no fill.

There are more clever ways to do this but I think this does a decent job and is clear in its execution.